# Api-Platform: Using Yaml config instead of annotations in SF 4

Tags: symfony4, api-platform.com

I'd like to use YAML instead of annotations in Api-Platform.

Instead of using the Api-Platform distribution, I have added the api-pack into my existing Symfony Flex project (`composer req api`).

The documentation says the YAML file should take place in `/config/api_platform/resources.yaml` but my entities aren't discovered.

Should I configure something somewhere else?

Thank you,
Ben

Answer (score 34, accepted):

The only thing you need to do is to add the following configuration:

```
api_platform:
    mapping:
        paths: ['%kernel.project_dir%/config/api_platform/resources']
```

I use a subfolder named `resources` inside to split the configuration into many files. Here is an example of configuration:

article.yaml

```
# /config/api_platform/resources/article.yaml
App\Domain\Article:
    attributes:
        normalization_context:
            groups: ['article_read']

    collectionOperations: []

    itemOperations:
        get:
            method: 'GET'
        put:
            method: 'PUT'
```

user.yaml (with more content in config)

```
# This file is inside /config/api_platform/resources/user.yaml
App\Domain\User:
    attributes:
        normalization_context:
            groups: ['user_read']
        denormalization_context:
            api_allow_update: true
            groups: ['user_write', 'user_avatar_write']
        filters:
            - 'App\Application\ApiPlatform\Filters\DeletedFilter'

    collectionOperations:
        get:
            method: 'GET'
            access_control: is_granted('VIEW', object)
            normalization_context: {'groups': ['user_read_collection']}
        post:
            method: 'POST'
            access_control: is_granted('CREATE', object)
            normalization_context:
                groups: ['user_post']

    itemOperations:
        get:
            method: 'GET'
            access_control: is_granted('VIEW', object)
```

Comment: Perfect answer. Thanks a lot Nek!

Comment: Hi, is there a solution to get "autocompletion" when using yaml instaed of annotation ? thanks

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem that you, I avoided the problem by using service decorations as described in the [documentation](https://api-platform.com/docs/core/swagger/).

<kbd>config/services.yaml</kbd>

```
# Customize Swagger documentation
'App\Swagger\SwaggerDecorator':
    decorates: 'api_platform.swagger.normalizer.documentation'
    arguments: [ '@App\Swagger\SwaggerDecorator.inner' ]
    autoconfigure: false
```

<kbd>src/Swagger/SwaggerDecorator.php</kbd>

```
<?php

namespace App\Swagger;

use Symfony\Component\Serializer\Normalizer\NormalizerInterface;

/**
 * @link https://api-platform.com/docs/core/swagger/
 */
final class SwaggerDecorator implements NormalizerInterface
{
    private $decorated;

    public function __construct(NormalizerInterface $decorated)
    {
        $this->decorated = $decorated;
    }

    public function normalize($object, $format = null, array $context = [])
    {
        $docs = $this->decorated->normalize($object, $format, $context);

        $customDefinition = [
            'name' => 'id',
            'description' => 'ID of user',
            'in' => 'path',
            'required' => 'true',
        ];

        $docs['paths']['/api/ben/stack_overflow/{id}']['post'] = [
            'summary' => 'SO example',
            'parameters' => [
                $customDefinition,
            ],
            'responses' => [
                '200' => [
                    'description' => 'OK',
                ],
                '400' => [
                    'description' => 'Error',
                ],
            ],
        ];
    }

    public function supportsNormalization($data, $format = null)
    {
        return $this->decorated->supportsNormalization($data, $format);
    }
}
```

The syntax is the same as in [Swagger](https://swagger.io/docs/specification/2-0/paths-and-operations/) but is written as PHP array instead of JSON.

It will generate the following Swagger documentation :

[image]

(I don't know yet how to change the `default` title)

Comment: If I need to create multiple routes using this decorator approach, what should I do?
All the examples I see creates only one route.

Comment: @JoaoVictorSouza duplicate and adapt `$customDefinition = …` and `$docs['paths'][…]`.

Comment: Do you have an example of a Post action? Showing the body request values? I cant seem to make it right

Comment: If you need overwrite a single response, you can do this by adding `swagger_context` or `openapi_context` (select which you used) and describe it by Swagger's scheme: https://swagger.io/docs/specification/describing-responses/