# Where is API Platform config for entity mapping is situated in the latest versions?

Tags: symfony, symfony4, api-platform.com

The documentation says that there is file `api/config/api_platform/resources.yaml` where I can map entities using yml. But neither in the distribution nor when I install API-platform as a package I can't find this file. Creation of the directory and file manually doesn't help.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In the context of a Symfony 4 project, the file can be located at `config/api_platform/resources.yaml`. If it doesn't exist, simply create it.

You can also use several files in order to define your mappings:

- `config/api_platform/resources/entity1.yaml`
- `config/api_platform/resources/entity2.yaml`

I suggest to use separate files since it's simpler to maintain than one big file.

You'll have to configure these paths in the `config/packages/api_platform.yaml` file:

```
api_platform:
    mapping:
        paths: ['%kernel.project_dir%/config/api_platform/resources']
```

See [Nek's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/49859729/2257664) for a complete example.

---

I find the documentation a little bit confusing about this, because in a Symfony project there's no `api/` directory at the root of the project.

Comment: @NikitaPimoshenko I updated my answer. You may need to modify the `paths` value, depending where you put your configuration files.

Comment: Maybe u know why i can't make POST/PUT overriden request the same URI as subresource's one?

Comment: Ok i found that it;s unavaialble now.

Comment: I'm sorry but I can help you about subresources.

Comment: You can? Or you can't? =) As far as i understoud subresources are now only readable and to create them differently each endpoint should be served via Custom Operation class as example in docs.

Comment: Yes, sorry for the typo but I never used subresources so I can't help you. But feel free to add another question about this issue!